time.sleep() not working in for loop with tweepy
I'm trying to download tweets from a specific account using the code below (python, package tweepy)
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import time


# Credenziali del 08/07/2024 Pagamento personale 
consumer_key = "consumer key >"
consumer_secret = "consumer secret>"
access_token  = "access token "
access_secret = "access secret "
bearer_token = "bearer token "


#AUT with client (V2)
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token, consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret, access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=access_secret,wait_on_rate_limit=True) # add wait_on_rate_limit 

# search tweets produced by a specific user relying on user ID 
end_time="2024-06-22T23:59:01Z" 
start_time="2024-06-10T23:59:01Z"
user_id="insert user id here" 


result = []
tweets = [] # Define containers to use in the loop defined below  
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets,
                                user_id=user_id,
                                end_time=end_time,
                                tweet_fields = ['id','referenced_tweets','text','context_annotations','created_at','geo','author_id','lang','public_metrics'],
                                user_fields =['id','name','username','url','public_metrics'],
                                start_time= start_time):
    for tweet in response.data:
        tweets.append(tweet)
        result.append({'id': tweet.id,
                       'author_id': tweet.author_id,
                       'lang': tweet.lang,
                       'text': tweet.text,
                       'created_at': tweet.created_at,
                       'retweets': tweet.public_metrics['retweet_count'],
                       'replies': tweet.public_metrics['reply_count'],
                       'likes': tweet.public_metrics['like_count'],
                       'quote_count': tweet.public_metrics['quote_count'],
                       'referenced_tweets': tweet.referenced_tweets,
                       'context_annotations': tweet.context_annotations,
                       'tweet_url': f"https://twitter.com/{tweet.author_id}/status/{tweet.id}"
                  })
        time.sleep(1) # introduce a delay of 1 second between each request
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
                                 
df.to_csv("mydf.csv", index=False)

the script works as long as the number of requests becomes higher. I have added a time.sleep(1) so to add an extra second pause. However, I keep receiving the same message Rate limit exceeded. Wait for xx seconds. I really do not know why, I have tried searching in many repo but I still not get what I am doing wrong.
Any suggestion is more than welcome!
As mentioned I have searched in some repo and the suggestion was to add a time.sleep() to the for loop.  Even increasing the time.sleep(2) the result is always the same. I keep receiving the same sleep message mentioned above.

Did you try the value of xx instead of 1 in sleep()?

yes I have tried but the results keeps being the same... I do not know why! Thanks!

https://developer.x.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits

"the script works as long as the number of requests becomes higher" did you mean to say "unless" instead of "as long as"?
